# Why doesn't my cron work?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I have an Ubuntu 14.04.5 installed and I'm trying to run a cron but it does not work.

```
$ whoami
root

$ crontab -e
#append at the end of the file
* * * * * env > /tmp/env_root.output
#save and quit :wq

$ less /var/log/cron.log
......
Sep 22 20:15:01 myserver CRON[2993]: (root) CMD (env > /tmp/env_root.output)

$ ls -la /tmp/env_root.output
ls: cannot access /tmp/env_root.output: No such file or directory
```

Why is this? I am root and I should be able to edit files, the Cron log shows it as being changed, but no file is there. If I run the command in the current GNU BASH shell or even in /bin/sh it works but not in Cron.

What am I doing wrong? Does Ubuntu have something like SELinux that I might have enabled by mistake? I provision my server with Ansible and I am not the only person working on the Ansible roles.

Thank you

EDIT: This is how my /etc/crontab looks and it runs /usr/bin/myscript.sh
https://paste.fedoraproject.org/433591/74650461/

Comment: It's hard to differentiate where your formatted output, commandlines and content of your crontab file begins and ends.  If you can edit your question and make this clearer I'm sure I could identify the problem.

Comment: Try `* * * * * /usr/bin/env > /tmp/env_root.output`

Comment: Thank you. I tried:

    * * * * * env >> /tmp/env_root.output
    * * * * * /usr/bin/env > /tmp/env_root.output
    * * * * * /usr/bin/env 2&>1 /tmp/env_root.output

None work :( > shoud work despite of the file not existing. I created the file and still no luck, it does not get populated. /usr/bin is in my path so adding full path does not help and sending stderr to the file does not work since env sends to stdout not stderr.

Comment: Strangely it works if I put my script in /etc/crontab instead of using contab -e

Comment: add the full path of `env` by getting the path of `env` by executing the command `which env`

Answer (score -1):

The best way to troubleshoot cron jobs is to watch the cron output in near-real-time.

This Q&A describes the process of breaking out `syslog` to make the system create a `cron.log` and to monitor it:

[16.04: How do I make cron create cron.log and monitor it in real time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966194/16-04-how-do-i-make-cron-create-cron-log-and-monitor-it-in-real-time/966195#966195)

It is very helpful to change the log level to 15 so it not only shows start times but also errors and stop times:

[How to change cron log level?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949996/how-to-change-cron-log-level/)